# keep the connection alive after specified time in swiftmailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

i am using `SwiftMailer` to send bulk emails. As my hosting server is a shared server so they do have a limit to send `25 emails in 5 min` and after that i have to send the rest of the emails manually.

To solve this issue i came across two plugis

[1. AntiFlood](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html)

[2. Throttler](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html)

but i dont know which one is the best suitable

```
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(25,300));
```

or

```
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin(
  5, Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin::MESSAGES_PER_MINUTE
));
```

can anyone help me to make it more clear that which is good to use here

Answer (score 0):

Both work OK, but there is no need to keep the connection alive.

Just create a cron job that runs your script every 5 minutes and send the emails.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the relation between connection reset and rate limiting? Does the calculation done through only one active connection?